# Error ASP.NET Core y SQLServer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

estoy realizando una api que devuelve los registros de una bbdd en sql server y al momento de compilar obtengo un error con Entity Frameworks que no encuentro como solucionarlo , buscando encontré que puede estar relacionado con las versiones de los paquetes que utilizo pero aun así no se por donde empezar...

ERROR: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'The database provider attempted to register an implementation of the 'IRelationalTypeMappingSource' service. This is not a service defined by Entity Framework and as such must be registered as a provider-specific service using the 'TryAddProviderSpecificServices' method."

Startup.cs

```
    using apiGestores.Models;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;


   namespace apiGestores.Context
   {
    public class AppDbContext :DbContext
   {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options)   //-> Aquí salta la           excepcion 
    {

    }
    public DbSet<GestoresBD> gestores_bd { get; set; }
}
```

}

Dejo una captura :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que si estas usando ASP NET Core, debe usar EF Core, además de que deben de ser versiones similares o iguales de NET Core.
Como usas SQL, debe usar estos

1. SQL:`Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`
2. Tool:`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` este es una herramienta
   para los cambios de contexto
3. [EF Core CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet): Para usar el cli para cambios de contexto desde la bash

Te dejo la siguiente pagina que es buenísima y te explica todas las cosas que puedes hacer con [EF Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: Gracias Jaime, el problema que tenia era una incopatibilidad de versiones del EF